# CountVectorizer with Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn for text processing, but my `CountVectorizer` isn't giving the output I expect.

My CSV file looks like:

```
"Text";"label"
"Here is sentence 1";"label1"
"I am sentence two";"label2"
...
```

and so on.

I want to use Bag-of-Words first in order to understand how SVM in python works:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

data = pd.read_csv(open('myfile.csv'),sep=';')

target = data["label"]
del data["label"]

# Creating Bag of Words
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(data)
X_train_counts.shape 
count_vect.vocabulary_.get(u'algorithm')
```

But when I do `print(X_train_counts.shape)` I see the output is only `(1,1)`, whereas I have 1048 rows with sentences.

What I am doing wrong? I am following [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) tutorial.

(Also the output of `count_vect.vocabulary_.get(u'algorithm')` is `None`.)

Comment: Why wouldn't `count_vect.vocabulary_.get(u'algorithm')` be `None`? The term is defined nowhere in your example.

Comment: @aryamccarthy ok. with algorithm it makes sense. But what is with the shape?

Comment: Your dataframe has two columns `Text` and `label` but clearly you only want to be running `CountVectorizer` on `data['Text']` column! Not on `data['label']` column.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is in `count_vect.fit_transform(data)`. The function expects an iterable that yields strings. Unfortunately, these are the wrong strings, which can be verified with a simple example.

```
for x in data:
    print(x)
# Text
```

Only the column names get printed; iterating gives columns instead of the values of `data['Text']`. You should do this:

```
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(data.Text)
X_train_counts.shape 
# (2, 5)
count_vect.vocabulary_
# {'am': 0, 'here': 1, 'is': 2, 'sentence': 3, 'two': 4}
```