# POS tags for train and test sets: ValueError

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to extract POS tags information from the following dataset

```
                 Sentences                                        Characters    Label
803    A Complete Bibliography of Scientific American...             128        1
1373    Mandated MVNO access would 'likely lead to del...            244        0 
1257    What is PANS/PANDAS? And Why Are Cases On The ...            212        0
2405    St Laurence School | Care • Inspire • Succ Hea...            124        1
2589    Study reveals: The 50 most Instagrammed island...            212        0
```

I am applying the following functions:

**(after Arya's suggestions)**

```
import nltk
 
tagged_sentences = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents()
cutoff = int(.75 * len(tagged_sentences))
    
import nltk
 
tagged_sentences = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents()
cutoff = int(.75 * len(tagged_sentences))

    def features(sentence, index):
        return {
            'word': sentence[index],
            'is_first_word': int(index == 0),
            'is_last_word': int(index == len(sentence) - 1),
            'is_capitalized': sentence[index][0].upper() == sentence[index][0],
            'is_all_upper': int(sentence[index].upper() == sentence[index]), 
            'is_all_lower': int(sentence[index].lower() == sentence[index]), 
            'prev_word': '' if index == 0 else sentence[index - 1],
            'next_word': '' if index == len(sentence) - 1 else sentence[index + 1],
            'prefix-1': sentence[index][0],
            'prefix-2': sentence[index][:2],
            'prefix-3': sentence[index][:3],
            'suffix-1': sentence[index][-1],
            'suffix-2': sentence[index][-2:],
            'suffix-3': sentence[index][-3:],
        }
```

Following the steps described in this article: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/pos-tagging-using-conditional-random-fields-92077e5eaa31, I would like to apply the same to my data (still considering `X`, `y`, for example `X=df[['Sentences','Characters']]`, and `y=df['Label']`.

```
X=df[['Sentences','Characters']]
y=df['Label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=40) 

train_df= pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1)
test_df = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)
```

This step should split the dataset into train and test. However, I have already this information, so I would not need to split the dataset into train and test.

```
def untag(tagged_sentences):
    return [w for w, t in tagged_sentences]


def prepareData(tagged_sentences):
    X,y=[],[]
    for sentence in tagged_sentences.Sentences:
        X.append([features(untag(sentence), index) for index in range(len(sentence))])
        y.append([tag for word,tag in sentence])
    return X,y
    
    X_train,y_train=prepareData(train_df)
    X_test,y_test=prepareData(test_df)
```

Running my dataset, I get the error:

```
----> 8 X_train,y_train=prepareData(train_df)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I hope you can tell me how to fix the ValueError.

I would need to assign tags using Sentences. Difficulties are in using my dataset (train and test) for doing the same that it was done in the link I shared.

Comment: Your problem doesn’t require a CRF because y isn’t structured; it’s a scalar. Instead, logistic regression will be enough.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. The variable training_sentences isn’t defined.

Comment: Sorry Arya, I am not getting what you mean. Could you please explain me a bit better? I think this other post can be useful, but I do know what I should replace there: https://nlpforhackers.io/training-pos-tagger/ I am trying to use the sentences in my dataframe. So training_sentence should be sentences from my train dataset (train_df). I think I put all the information there, but am happy to provide more info

Comment: Where are you getting your POS tags from? All I see is L, which is 0 or 1 for the whole sentence.

Comment: Okay, this is a digression. Please focus on providing a [mre]. Otherwise, we can’t help fix the ValueError. Separately, if this is a classification problem where a sequence gets labeled as only 0 or 1, you need only logistic regression, not a CRF. A CRF produces a structured output. Your output is just a 0 or 1 (a scalar). It is unstructured.

Comment: `training_sentences` still isn't defined.

Comment: Updated. Thank you for letting me noticed that

Comment: ```[w for w, t in sentences]``` how is this supposed to work on df['Sentences'] ? this is the source of your error

Comment: @StupidWolf Yep, we had to unpeel other problems to get to that one. We're discussing it in chat below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I see the problem. Well, the three problems.

### Problem 1. `prepareData` variable names

You're not copying from [the tutorial you used](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/pos-tagging-using-conditional-random-fields-92077e5eaa31) carefully.
This is how they define `prepareData`:

```
def prepareData(tagged_sentences):
    X,y=[],[]
    for sentences in tagged_sentences:
        X.append([features(untag(sentences), index) for index in range(len(sentences))])
        y.append([tag for word,tag in sentences])
    return X,y
```

(Incidentally, they called a variable `sentences` instead of `sentence`, which is a horribly confusing naming convention because it holds a single `sentence`.

But when you copied the tutorial, you changed the name `tagged_sentences` in two places, each to different things!

As the name of the function parameter, you changed it to `sentences`, which is already used. As the name of a variable inside the function, you changed it to `training_sentences`. Both of these names are going to confuse you, because they have other meanings in your code. But they should match! Try renaming it to `tagged_sentences` in both places.

### Problem 2. `prepareData` isn't designed for `DataFrame`s.

Once you fix that problem, you'll have a new one. The tutorial isn't using a `DataFrame`. It's using a list. You will run into problems on the line:

```
    for sentences in tagged_sentences:
```

because looping over a Pandas `DataFrame` loops over the column names. (See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083683/countvectorizer-with-pandas-dataframe/44083903#44083903).)

Instead, what you want is to look at only the sentences.

Change that line to:

```
    for sentences in tagged_sentences.Sentences:
```

This way, you get only the `Series` you care about. (You weren't using the `Characters` column anyway!)

### Problem 3. You're not doing POS tagging! You don't need a CRF!

I'm trying to be clear here. POS tagging means that for every input word in a sentence, you predict a label for that word. (The label is the word's part of speech.)

You aren't doing that. You are creating *one* label for the *entire* sentence. (See your `Label` column.) For that style of problem, you don't need a CRF. There's no *chain* of outputs. Logistic regression is the equivalent model that does what you need.

Comment: Thank you Arya. I will implement soon you suggestions and see if it works. Just for clarification: column 'Label' in my dataframe is not related to POS tagging (it is a Status variable)

Comment: Yes, and you said `y=df['Label']`. You're preparing your data to predict that, instead of to predict POS tags.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wanted to use POS tags as features. In this project: https://github.com/nishitpatel01/Fake_News_Detection/blob/master/FeatureSelection.py POS tags are used as features. I have been trying to follow that

Comment: Yeah, that's a completely fine, normal thing to do. You still don't need a CRF for that, because you're not predicting a sequence.

Comment: I am still getting the same error because of this step: `---> 45         X.append([features(untag(sentence), index) for index in range(len(sentence))])` and `36 def untag(tagged_sentences):
---> 37     return [w for w, t in tagged_sentences]` . The error is: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). I am going to updated the question, in order to show the steps I followed, after the changes you suggested. Thank you for your help

Comment: Your sentences aren't tagged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228872/discussion-between-ldm-and-arya-mccarthy).